# Delete content of folders with same name in different subdirectories

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

I am using Windows 10.

I have many same named folders (suppose the name "data") in different subdirectories of a base directory (here "d:\dir").

How can I delete the content (containing only files) of all the folders named "data" without deleting themselves?

E.g. for three folders:

```
d:\dir\data
d:\dir\tmp1\data
d:\dir\tmp3\tmp2\data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within a Windows command prompt window the following command line can be used to delete just all files (not folders) in all `data` directories of `D:\dir` and its subdirectories:

```
for /F "delims=" %I in ('dir "D:\dir\*data" /AD /B /S 2^>nul ^| findstr /E /I /C:"\data"') do @del /A /F /Q "%I\*"
```

The same command line would be written as follows in a Windows batch file:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "D:\dir\*data" /AD /B /S 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /C:"\data"') do del /A /F /Q "%%I\*"
```

The command **FOR** executes in a separate command process started with `%ComSpec% /C` in background the command line:

```
dir "D:\dir\*data" /AD /B /S 2>nul | C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe /I /E /C:"\data"
```

The environment variable `ComSpec` is usually defined as `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` as it can be seen on looking on the **system** environment variables in Windows **Control Panel - System - Advanced system settings - Environment Variables...**. The environment variable `SystemRoot` is defined by default with path to Windows directory. In other words **FOR** executes by default on most Windows PCs `C:\Windows\System32.exe` with option `/C` and the command line specified between `('` and `')`. See also Wikipedia article with a list of predefined [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

The command **DIR** outputs to handle **STDOUT** (standard output)

- in bare format because of option `/B`
- just names of directories because of option `/AD` (attribute directory)
- with full path because of option `/S`
- matching the wildcard pattern `*data`
- in specified directory `D:\dir`
- and all its subdirectories also because of option `/S`.

**DIR** would output an error message to handle **STDERR** (standard error) on no directory entry matching these criteria. This error message is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL** with `2>nul`.

So the output of **DIR** is for given example:

```
D:\dir\data
D:\dir\tmp1\data
D:\dir\tmp3\tmp2\data
```

The output of **DIR** to handle **STDOUT** is redirected with `|` to handle **STDIN** (standard input) of next command **FINDSTR**.

**FINDSTR** searches in stream read from **STDIN** line by line

- case-insensitive because of option `/I`
- the literally interpreted string `\data`
- which must be found at end of a line because of option `/E`.

So **FINDSTR** outputs to handle **STDOUT** of background command process all lines with `\data` at end of line which is for the given example again:

```
D:\dir\data
D:\dir\tmp1\data
D:\dir\tmp3\tmp2\data
```

Filtering output of command **DIR** with **FINDSTR** is necessary to exclude a directory with a name like `MyData` which is also output by **DIR** because of wildcard `*` which is required to get not output all subdirectories of `D:\dir\data` and its subdirectories, but all `data` directories in `D:\dir` and its subdirectories.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line in a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** with option `/F` captures everything output finally to handle **STDOUT** of started command process and processes this output line by line after termination of started `cmd.exe`.

Empty lines are always ignored by **FOR**, but there are not empty lines output by **DIR** and **FINDSTR**.

**FOR** ignores by default also all lines starting with a `;` which is the default end of line character. But all lines captured by **FOR** start in this case never with a semicolon because of all lines start with `D:`. So the default `eol=;` can be kept. Otherwise `eol=|` is usually the best on processing a file/folder names list as no file/folder name can contain the vertical bar.

**FOR** would split up by default every line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab character as string delimiters and would assign just first space/tab separated string to specified loop variable `I`. A folder name in path of a `data` directory could contain a space character. For that reason an empty list of delimiters is specified with `delims=` which disables line splitting behavior resulting in getting assigned to loop variable `I` always the full qualified name of a found `data` folder.

**FOR** executes for every `data` directory assigned to `I` the command:

```
del /A /F /Q "%I\*"
```

`%I` is replaced before execution of **DEL** by full qualified directory name assigned currently to loop variable `I`.

The command **DEL** is for deleting files. It does not delete directories. The option `/A` is used to delete all files independent on their attributes including files with hidden attribute set which **DEL** would not delete without option `/A`. The option `/F` is required to force also a deletion of a file with read-only attribute set which would not be deleted without option `/F`. The option `/Q` is used to suppress the query asking user if really all files matched by `*` should be deleted by **DEL**.

The full qualified directory name must be enclosed in double quotes because it could contain a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` which requires the usage of `"` around an argument string of a command as explained by help of **CMD**  on last help page which is output on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?`.

Please note that **DEL** can't delete files on which the user as no NTFS permissions to delete files or which are currently opened by an application in a manner which prevents the deletion of the file while being opened by the application. **DEL** outputs an error message for every file which cannot be deleted due to missing NTFS or file access permissions.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`

Answer (score 1):

Following your example, you'd have to call:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse d:\dir | Where-Object { ($_.DirectoryName) -and (Split-Path $_.DirectoryName -Leaf) -eq 'data' } | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursively enumerate all folders with the name "data", then delete their content.

```
$base_dir = 'D:\dir'
$name     = 'data'

Get-ChildItem $base_dir -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer -and
    $_.Name -eq $name
} | Select-Object -Expand FullName | ForEach-Object {
    Remove-Item "$_\*" -Recurse -Force
}
```

In PowerShell v3 and newer you can replace the filter condition `$_.PSIsContainer` by using the parameter `-Directory` with `Get-ChildItem`.